# Pgfplots: Linewidth when using \ref in custom legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm creating a custom legend for some `pgfplots` graph by drawing a node containing a shortstack.
Inside the node I'm using `\ref{}` to insert correct line-styles in front of my text labels.

The problem is that while the lines in the graph are printed with `line width=1pt`, the lines from `\ref` are the standard thin size of pgfplots.

This does not happen when using the normal pgfplots legend setup (`\addlegendentry`), but this is not possible in this graph since the legend either needs to contain extra information or is a common legend for 2 different axis.

So how can I control the line width when using `\ref`?

Comment: Please register your account at Stack Overflow and at TeX Stack Exchange to be able to comment on your question and its answers after the migration, and to accept an answer.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you specified the line width incorrectly. Here's an example that shows that `\ref` does indeed produce the correct line width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[line width=2pt] {rnd}; \label{graph1}
\addplot {rnd}; \label{graph2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\ref{graph1} 2pt line; \qquad \ref{graph2} normal line
\end{document}
```

Comment: and how do you control the length of the ref-lines?

Comment: @Ktree It seems the thickness is controlled automatically. But you may need to compile twice to see the legend changes. One does not have to control it explicitly.