# Thickening the line in legend representation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have plotted several graphs using "gnuplot" and post-processed the graphs in "GIMP". I decided to remove the legend within the graph and place the legend separately below my set of graphs. I have used the script of "Christian Feuersänger" mentioned in [Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture/54834#54834).

In general I would like to use the "sharp plot" functionality for my legend but the thickness of the lines shown is very small. I tried to use the scaling factor but it scales along the x-axis whereas I would like to scale it along the y-axis. Any hints on how this could be done?

Thanks;
Saideep

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I tried several variations of scale like "scale x, scale y, width, height" etc. But none worked.

"**line width=x pt**" is the exact thing that I was searching for. From this post:
[Pgfplots: Linewidth when using \ref in custom legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26038/pgfplots-linewidth-when-using-ref-in-custom-legend).